Cannot open port 9
When I try to do port forwarding in Huawei WS5200 router so I can use Wake on LAN even if I am not on the same network as my computer, but when I put those configurations:

I still cant use WOL from another network. I tested it form wake on LAN application by Mike webb on Android using mobile internet (not the same local network) And checked the port status using canyouseeme.org
I turned off firewall.

Chester gillon,  that question is closed, so I opened a new one with more details

The right thing to do is to improve the old question (by editing it) and to have it reopened, not to spam the site with another copy of the question.

How to have it reopened?

And it's not a copy bruh
